# fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git- Error in Xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

I want to rename my project. For that, I have to just choose project name press(command 
+1) , and after that I can able to  edit my project name.
My project is in SVN, I have deleted the local git repositories.
Now, whenever I want to rename my project, fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git..this errors come.
Any idea, why this is happening and how to fix this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try this:

- Go to Organizer <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>
- Click repositories
- Delete any Git repositories that reference your project by selecting the repo on the left and clicking <kbd>Backspace</kbd>
- Restart XCode before renaming.

Comment: Thnx James, it really save some times for me. Also, One has to quit Xcode and again run the project to rename that.

Comment: I added your comment to my answer.